# curl post request is not working with option --http2, but it works fine when I use --http2-prior-knowledge

Tags: spring-boot, curl, tls1.2, http2, tomcat9

I have created spring-boot application with tomcat 9.0.16, spring-boot 2.1.3.RELEASE, JDK1.8. 
When I am making curl post request with --http2 its saying "curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer".

but when I use --http-prior-knowledge it works fine.

my application.property file

```
server.port=8080
server.http2.enabled=true
```

and congif file

```
@Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer tomcatCustomizer() {
        return (container) -> {
            if (container instanceof TomcatServletWebServerFactory) {
                ((TomcatServletWebServerFactory) container)
                        .addConnectorCustomizers((connector) -> {
                            connector.addUpgradeProtocol(new Http2Protocol());
                        });
            }
        };
    }
```

1. for curl -vvv --http2 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -XPOST http://localhost:8080/save -d '{"xyz":"xyz"}'
   logs of curl->

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 150000 ms for 3 (transfer 0x7fc78a808a00)
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x7fc78a808a00)
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /save HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
> Upgrade: h2c
> HTTP2-Settings: AAMAAABkAARAAAAAAAIAAAAA
> Content-Type: application/json
> Postman-Token: 52e0708b-ce97-4baa-a567-2dabc675f3dd
> cache-control: no-cache
> Content-Length: 702
>
* upload completely sent off: 702 out of 702 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 101
< Connection: Upgrade
< Upgrade: h2c
< Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2019 12:29:18 GMT
* Received 101
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 200)!
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Failed receiving HTTP2 data
* Send failure: Broken pipe
* Failed sending HTTP2 data
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

2. curl -vvv --http2-prior-knowledge -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Postman-Token: 52e0708b-ce97-4baa-a567-2dabc675f3dd' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -XPOST http://localhost:8080/save -d '{"xyz":"xyz"}'

```
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x7fc5c0808a00)
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 150000 ms for 3 (transfer 0x7fc5c0808a00)
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x7fc5c0808a00)
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7fc5c0808a00)
> POST /save HTTP/2
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Postman-Token: 52e0708b-ce97-4baa-a567-2dabc675f3dd
> cache-control: no-cache
> Content-Length: 702
>
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 200)!
< HTTP/2 200
< content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< date: Wed, 27 Mar 2019 12:32:26 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
true%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use a `POST` method to perform an HTTP/1.1 upgrade, so Tomcat is probably choking on your first request (`curl --http2 ...`) for that reason.

I am the HTTP/2 implementer in Jetty, and Jetty also does not upgrade to HTTP/2 in that case, although it responds with HTTP/1.1 200 to the request, rather than choking.

Converting the first request to a `GET` without content, the upgrade succeeds in Jetty with a HTTP/1.1 101 response, as expected.

The second request is not an HTTP/1.1 upgrade, but a prior knowledge HTTP/2 request; there is no upgrade and therefore no limitation as to what HTTP method you can use, so the request succeeds in both Jetty and Tomcat.

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer and very true it's actually a defect. The http2 spec does not mandate `GET` requests for `h2c` upgrades. So upgrading from an initial `POST` request is both perfectly fine and what application developers are expecting (and it [works with netty](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7079) ).